# Non-traditional control for three hole bathroom faucet

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I don't like having to control hot water and cold water flow separately. 
I want to be able to change temperature (while maintaing flow) without having to coordinate two handles, or change flow (while maintaining temperature). A single handle bathroom faucet is sufficient for me. I don't know whether there exists designs where one handle controls hot/cold mix while the other handle controls water flow. If such a design exists, that would work for me as well. There could also be other designs that I would enjoy using.

However, I can't replace my current bathroom faucet with a single handle faucet because my counter top has 3 holes (8 inches apart from left handle to right handle).

What are my options for a replacement bathroom faucet?

Answer (score 1):

An Escutcheon or Deck Plate can cover the outer 2 holes, allowing you to use any 1-hole faucet you like. The downside is that they can be quite large, and the selection at 8 inches isn't that great. [Example product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005SQ8A44).
(Whether this would fit with your preferred style is a different question.)

You could also have a 1-hole faucet, put a soap dispenser in one of the holes, and a simple cover over the third. That would be less than ideal, but so would an escutcheon, and it might work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall if it was 6 or 8 inch spacing (that's typically measured "center to center" and 8" is more common in kitchen faucets than bethroom faucets), but I replaced a 2-handle 3 hole with a 1-handle 3 hole faucet in my bathroom when the 2-handle version expired from old age. For that matter my kitchen sink is the same, but I didn't replace it, it came that way.

They are common.